# how do i close a specefic activity and get to previous activity Programatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

Here i have a few activities that consist different menus in my app..

The problem is that i want to add a are you sure popup box to exit the current menu and return back but calling finish() method on the click event of yes button of popup box causes all activities to terminate and app exits...

I want to make a way to terminate only the foreground activity and
return to last activity programatically (i.e without using back key)

Answer (score 0):

Can u post some source code regarding how you start you new activities? Are you starting multiple activities at all? finish() method only finishes the current activity and not the entire stack of activities, thus the system automatically brings to front the previous activity from the stack. I can't understand your question please provide some further details.